# How to download a website from web archive

Tags: apache, unix, ubuntu, wget, darwin

I almost spent a month trying to figure out how to download a website from web archive from `web.archive.org`

```
sudo wget --limit-rate=200k --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla http://web.archive.org/web/20031208182936/http://www.domain.com/****.php
```

I was looking for a command that would grab the website and follow links from a javascript dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

sudo wget --limit-rate=200k --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla http://web.archive.org/web/20031208182936/http://www.domain.com/****.php